# Google Analytics Real Time Event Not triggering on Page Load

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to send user data to GA on my page load when user is logged in(once home page loaded). I have below **Tags and trigger(having custom event)** created, but the event is not triggering. I have click event which is working fine.Not sure why on page load it is not working.

**datalayer** is like below **email** property used as condition to trigger event.If not with enhanced commerce what is the other way to get event triggered and data is pushed to GA

```
   dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'userdata',
          'ecommerce': {
             'currencyCode': 'DLR',
             'User': {
                     'email': userEmail,
                     'UserName': userName,
                     'OutletNumber': outletNumber
              }
           }
  });
```

[image: Tag]

[image: GA Trigger]

[image: **email** variable]

Comment: Can you show how did you setup "email" variable?

Comment: What is the purpose of you using EEcomm? `User` is not a recognised ecomm object. Try taking all of the `User` parameters out to the root dataLayer push. You also have to configure and reference the dataLayer keys appropriately with {{}}.

Comment: @Matus, @nyuen

I have attached email variable and changed datalayer to
                      `dataLayer.push({
                          'event': 'userdata',
                          'ecommerce': {
                              'currencyCode': 'DLR',                              
                                'email': userEmail,
                                'UserName': userName,
                                'OutletNumber': outletNumber                               
                           }`
                    });

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem @Adi. "email" is not key for datalyer variable. It's inside "ecommerce" as part of value. The simplest fix for you would be just to replicate "email": userEmail as separate value e.g.:

```
 dataLayer.push({ 
  'event': 'userdata', 
  'email': userEmail, 
  'ecommerce': { 'currencyCode': 'DLR', 'email': userEmail, 'UserName': userName, 'OutletNumber': outletNumber }
});
```

Comment: Hello @Matus. I added 'email' as own separate property as you mentioned , but still not getting event triggered.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the userEmail is defined and properly set when you call the dataLayer.push ?

Comment: Yes @Matus. I am setting the value and able to see in dataslayer that event is showing 

`event userdata
email abc@gmail.com
-ecommerce object
         .currencyCode DLR
         .email abc@gmail.com
         .UserName ABC
         .OutletNumber  12385769`

Comment: That's strange, if you can see the event in the dataslayer there is probably a problem with your Firing Triggers. In your very first screenshot the image cuts of just before I can see the "Firing Triggers" - can you post full screenshot of it?

Comment: The second screenshot is what trigger is. In first screenshot it is Tag and only name of trigger below the "Firsing Triggers"